# How do I set up an Azure trigger that detects an AD change in another Directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-triggers

I have a web API that gets called from Azure but I don't know how to get it to run when there is a change in the Azure AD. So basically:

- Azure logic app listens for change in Directory.
- Azure AD detects change in Directory.
- Logic app runs.

How do I get the logic app to listen for this change?

Comment: Hey Joey I'd recommend voting that they add this process. Vote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/31827406-azure-ad-connector-add-triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Azure Ad triggered when directory is modified is **not support**.

You could upvote this [issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/31827406-azure-ad-connector-add-triggers) to promote the feature to get achieve. Or you could give your feedback with your idea of azure logic app there.